# Object color difference between Forge Viewer and Tekla

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have several Tekla models exported as IFC using a color schema. The visual result on Forge Viewer 6.* appears different from the original

[Tekla original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnfC4.png)

[Forge viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYls4.png)

How can I make colors consistent with the pattern used in modeling?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Forge Model Derivative service translation. Would you mind sharing the IFC file with us on forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com? We would then pass the file to the translation dev. team and ask them to investigate the issue further.

Comment: Thanks Petr. I sent the file to to Forge support.